# Add to an array value (+1)

Tags: php

I have an array

```
$hourly = array(
        "01" => "0",
        "02" => "0",
        "03" => "0",
        "04" => "0",
        "05" => "0",
        "06" => "0",
        "07" => "0",
        "08" => "0",
        "09" => "0",
        "10" => "0",
        "11" => "0",
        "12" => "0",
        "13" => "0",
        "14" => "0",
        "15" => "0",
        "16" => "0",
        "17" => "0",
        "18" => "0",
        "19" => "0",
        "20" => "0",
        "21" => "0",
        "22" => "0",
        "23" => "0"
            );
```

And I have a bunch of data like "01" and "03" and "21" and I want to add (+1) to that specific value in the array. So with the data set "01","03","21","01","22" the resulting array would be

```
$hourly = array(
        "01" => "2",
        "02" => "0",
        "03" => "1",
        "04" => "0",
        "05" => "0",
        "06" => "0",
        "07" => "0",
        "08" => "0",
        "09" => "0",
        "10" => "0",
        "11" => "0",
        "12" => "0",
        "13" => "0",
        "14" => "0",
        "15" => "0",
        "16" => "0",
        "17" => "0",
        "18" => "0",
        "19" => "0",
        "20" => "0",
        "21" => "1",
        "22" => "1",
        "23" => "0"
            );
```

How could I go about doing that? Is there a function to add 1 to an array element?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? The sample data/explanation don't quite sync.

Comment: He wants to increment by 1 the values that appear in the other array.

Comment: If you want to do mathematical operations on them, why are your array values strings and not integers?

Comment: I know this question is ancient history, but for the benefit of others who arrive here, 1) notice that $hourly probably should have "00" as the first index, and 2) make sure you read the answers below that discuss the fact that the indexes with leading zeros will be strings, while the others will be converted to integers!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
$hours = array("01", "03", "21" );
foreach($hours as $hour) {
   $hourly[$hour] += 1;
}
```

Answer (score 23):

```
$updates = array("01","03","21","01","22");
foreach($updates as $num) {
    $hourly[$num]++;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Normally, you'd be able to do:

```
$array["key"]++;
```

However, your arrays have a few peculiarities you should fix;

- Your key values are actually strings. If you want numbers you can increment, you should use numbers from the beginning. If you store a string and increment it with the syntax above, it'll be turned into an integer.
- Arrays store string or a numbers as keys. You're using both. "01" will be stored as a string key, "10" will be stored as a number. Consider storing only numbers as keys.

None of these make your script not work, but the inconsistency and unnecessary performance hit are avoidable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a completely "functional" approach, **even if it's PHP** and even id its not very beautiful ;-)
But it works (PHP >= 5.3.0):

```
...

$fr = 1; $to = 23;

# generate original Array
$hourly = array_combine(
  array_map( function($n){return sprintf("%02s",$n);}, range($fr,$to) ), # Keys
  array_map( function($n){return 0;}, range($fr,$to) )                   # Values
);

$updates = Array('01','03','21','01','22');

# update values based on keys found in $updates
array_walk( $updates, function($u){global $hourly; $hourly[$u]++;} );

...
```

Regards

rbo

Comment: Entirely too complex for what OP asked

Answer (score 0):

You could construct an array with the updated info (`$new = array('01' => '02','03' => '01',)` etc and then use `array_replace($hourly,$new)` or `array_merge($hourly,$new)`. There are probably alternative functions too.

Answer (score 0):

Dealing with leading zeros is messy, no matter which way you approach it.  You are either going to have to deal with mixed string/integer indexes, OR you are going to have to make sure you force everything into integer, but then remember to put the leading zero back if displaying it is important.

If you ever manipulate an array with something like `array_merge()`, you had better force all indexes to integer, because it will renumber integer indexes if there are gaps in the sequence.

### If you want to preserve the leading zeros in the indexes

The following will only work if the inputs are **really** in an array and the values are consistent (ie "one" always occurs as "01" and never as "1" (or vice-versa)):

```php
$counts = array_count_values( $inputs );
```

Because of the leading zeros for values <10 they are interpreted as strings, which you may or may not notice depending on how you access the counts.  If you use a hardcoded index, you need to be sure to include the leading zero, eg `$counts["01"]` not `$counts["1"]`.  If you only care about the values that have been seen, a simple `foreach...as` will suffice:

```php
foreach( $counts as $value => $count ){ print "$value => $count\n"; }
```

If you are going to iterate through every possible value (or otherwise access them randomly), you need a bit of a kludge:

```php
function lpad( $index ){ return str_pad($index,2,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT); }
for($i=0;$i<24;$i++){ print ($counts[lpad($i)]??0)." "; }
```

or if you want to avoid a function call for performance

```php
$lpad = array_keys($hourly); ### IMPORTANT! ASSUMES $hourly ACTUALLY STARTS WITH "00"
for($i=0;$i<24;$i++){ print ($counts[$lpad[$i]]??0)." "; }
```

If you have a version of PHP that doesn't have `??` the body of the `for` loop should be something like

```php
print (is_null( $p = $counts[$lpad[$i]] )? 0 : $p )." ";
```

### If you want to force indexes with leading zeros into integers

Sparse counts (some hours skipped if they never appear)

```php
$counts = array_reduce( $inputs, function($c, $i){ $c[(integer)$i]++; return $c; }, array() );
```

Full range of counts (all hours, even if count is zero)

```php
$counts = array_reduce( $inputs, function($c, $i){ $c[(integer)$i]++; return $c; }, array_fill( 0, 24, 0 ));
```