# How to add +2 to array elements without using foreach?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to add +2 to an array elements without looping(foreach).

```
$arr=array(5,6,8,0,55,64,1);
```

wanted output:

```
$arr=array(7,8,10,2,57,66,3)
```

Comment: Have you considered using a for or foreach loop?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

Comment: can you tell me why exactly you want to do that? I mean whats your point?

Comment: No. I need output without using for and foreach

Comment: `foreach($a as $arr) {$arr[$a] += 2; }` from [AQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3478227/add-to-an-array-value-1)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan he says without looping(foreach).

Comment: @imsiso I don't know PHP, but I search on web, I thought it should be essay..yes foreach is loop and not as per OP need Thanks!

Comment: What is the reason to avoid an explicit loop? Are you learning functional-style programming, or just trying to code golf?

Comment: yes,functional-style programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Then [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.array-map.php) is you friend  :

```
function foo($n) { return($n + 2); }
$arr = array(5,6,8,0,55,64,1);
$ouput = array_map("foo", $arr);
```

**EDIT** after the answer of Gautam3164 : [array_walk](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.array-walk.php) is also an option, indeed. Just dont forget that array_map *returns a new array* when array_walk takes a reference and *updates your array*.

Comment: nice. thanks gautam too.

Comment: Yes @Herode you are right..I didnt gave array_map only bec of this only

Comment: Anyway good ans of yours too.

Answer (score 3):

```
// PHP 5.3+ anonmymous function.
$output = array_map(function($val) { return $val+2; }, $arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
array_walk($array, function(&$item) { $item += 2; });
```